# How to diagnose docker compose "Attaching to ..." taking a long time?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

We have a repo that uses a python subprocess to call docker compose and run a container that processes an input file and produces a new output file. For most files this works as expected, but it appears that as the file grows in size the "Attaching to ..." step takes significantly longer.

I am not sure where to look to diagnose the cause of this and resolve it.

I have experimented with adding a `.dockerignore` but this makes no difference. And given that the attaching only takes longer as the input file is larger I don't think this is the cause.

This is how compose is called in the python code:

```
compose = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)   
while True:
  line = compose.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  print(line.decode())
```

Where `cmd` will be this:

```
docker compose -f /path/to/install/location/service_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/file_generator/docker-compose.yml up service_1
```

Example compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service_1:
    image: some/image:latest
    environment:
      - PAYLOAD=${PAYLOAD}
      - ARGS=${DMRPP_ARGS}
    volumes:
      - ${INPUT_FILES_PATH:-/tmp}:/usr/share/
```

Using a `16mb` input file:

```
$ time service -p /some/path/to/inputs/ 

Container service_1 Created
Attaching to service_1 <- Gets delayed here for all but the last ~1.0 seconds of the execution
service_1  | ...logs...
service_1 exited with code 0

real    1m39.291s
user    0m0.261s
sys     0m0.093s
```

Using a `924K` input file:

```
$ time service -p /some/path/to/inputs/ --no-validate 

Container service_1 Created
Attaching to service_1
service_1  | ...logs...
service_1 exited with code 0

real    0m3.534s
user    0m0.262s
sys     0m0.113s
```

Comment: What is your host system, and what "kind" of Docker are you using?  If you're using Docker Desktop and it needs to actually copy files for a bind mount, this is a setup that is known to sometimes be slow.  If the goal of this task is to process a file that exists locally, would it be easier to directly `subprocess.call()` the other program, without involving Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze The host system is an Ubuntu VM but this python package is supposed to be cross platform. We depend on a 3rd party docker image to produce the outputs and we add a few changes on top of it. I don't think we could go without docker unless you are suggesting something I have misunderstood?